# How to make behave a pod saved in a variable like `$=pod`?

Tags: raku

Is it possible to convert a pod code which is save in a variable in a way that it behaves like a `$=pod` when used with pod2text?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6
use v6;
use Pod::To::Text;

my $code = $*PROGRAM.slurp;
my $pod = $code.subst( / ^ .+ \n <?before '=begin pod'> /, '' );

# convert $pod so it works with pod2text like $=pod does

say pod2text $pod;
say "==============";
say pod2text $=pod;

=begin pod

=head1 NAME

Test pod

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This is a test.

=end pod
```

Comment: See also [Print embedded Pod as formatted text with termcap escapes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55746131/2173773)

Comment: Seems like `pod2text` expects some kind of `Pod::` object as input (and not just a string) in order to do the conversion to text, see [the source code](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/lib/Pod/To/Text.pm6#L13)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `$=pod` variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_=_twigil) contains an [`Array`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Array) of values that are each an instance of (a sub-class of) [`Pod::Block`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Pod::Block). So you need to reproduce that.

## Letting the Rakudo compiler do all the work

If you compile some P6 code with a P6 compiler then any Pod in it is supposed to be automatically compiled, and the `$=pod` variable automatically initialized to contain the results of the Pod compilation. Using Rakudo:

```
=begin foo
foo-text
=end foo

say $=pod;
```

displays:

```
[Pod::Block::Named{:name("foo")}
  Pod::Block::Para
    foo-text
]
```

Having glanced over the relevant compiler modules ([grammar](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/PodGrammar.nqp), [actions](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/PodActions.nqp), [compiling wrapper](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/Pod.nqp)) I suspect it would take a fair amount of effort to understand it. It's possible that the fruit of that understanding will be the ability to use some of this code as is but I suspect it's at least equally likely you can't without refactoring the compiler code to some degree.

## Working from the ground up

The following `$pod` will also be accepted by `pod2text`:

```
my $pod =
  [Pod::Block::Named.new:
     :name("foo"),
     :contents[Pod::Block::Para.new:
       :contents["foo-text"]]];

say $pod; # displays same result as for `$=pod` above
```

## A solution?

Presumably the solution you seek is somewhere between these extremes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Pod::Load`](https://github.com/JJ/p6-pod-load):

This is your program:

```
use v6;
use Pod::To::Text;

=begin pod

=head1 NAME

Test pod

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This is a test.

=end pod
```

And this is where you load it:

```
use Pod::Load;

use Pod::To::Text;

my $pod = load( "get-pod.p6" );
dd $pod;

say pod2text $pod;
```

Perl6 itself is parsing the Pod along with the rest of the program, so what @raiph has answered is also valid, and, for that matter, the $=pod you have used in your program.